# HEMA Wrestling Guide

Tags: wrestling, books, historic-european

I've been learning Italian Longsword, a style of HEMA (Historic European Martial Arts) for several months now, heavily using [The Swordsman's Companion](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9526793404) as a teacher and guide. It has been superb teacher, and most techniques and exercises have been well explained, and what isn't well explained often becomes evident from attempting the techniques.

This is, however, not about Italian Longsword, but wrestling. Several respectable sources (Such as [Matt Easton of Scholagladitoria](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6V2Uf06NrFc)) mention that wrestling was a key component of many HEMA systems.

This leads to my question: is there such a book like "The Swordsman's Companion," but for **wrestling/pugilism in HEMA**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes there are treatises regarding Wrestling and Swordsmanship.**

As can be seen on ARMA's [Master Ott's Wrestling](http://www.thearma.org/Manuals/master-ott-wrestling.html#.VkYNQXYrLDc):

> - Hans Talhoffer (1443), Ms.Chart.A.558 (HK 20)
> - Peter von Danzig, Cod.44 A 8 (Cod. 1449)(HK 42)
> - Jud Lew, Cod.I.6.40.3 (HK 5)
> - Paulus Kal ,Cgm 1507
> - Hans von Speyer, M.I.29 1491 (HK 43)
> - Paulus Hector Mair, Mscr. Dresd. C 93/94 (HK 15, 34, 51)
> - Jörg Wilhalm, Cgm 3712 (HK 39)

You can also see the treatises on Wiktenauer's (HEMA Alliance Project) [Ott Jud](http://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Ott_Jud#Treatise) page.

If you would like a modern book on the subject, you can look at [Medieval Wrestling: Modern Practice of a 15th-Century Art](http://www.freelanceacademypress.com/medievalwrestling.aspx) by [Jessica Finley](https://www.facebook.com/jessicafinley21/photos) available from Freelance Academy Press.